# Resonant frequency of a three phase thyristor rectifier

Tags: rectifier, resonance, thyristor

I am trying to inspect how my circuit behaves at operating points around resonant frequency. Is resonant frequency simple equal to 1/(2*Pi*sqrt(L*C)) = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(590uH*240uF)) = 423 Hz (see the circuit diagram)? Or I have to consider all generator inductances ?

Thanks in advance
[image: three phase thyristor rectifier circuit]